# MPAndroidChart Intent Passing Data Error Null Object References

Tags: javascript, android, null, nullreferenceexception, mpandroidchart

Actually, I'm not a programmer but I have an assignment that I should finish. I have asked people around me and look at other questions, but I still can't implement it in my work.
Well, I'm gonna make a program that can calculate a column.
So I calculate it on the first activity, then pass the result to another activity.
In the second activity, I want to show a Scatter Diagram, using MPAndroid Chart.
*I have try my codes with a random numbers, and it work. But when I pass the data, the app is crash,* and here is my logcat :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.trim()' on a null object reference
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1838)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)
    at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:451)
    at com.example.diagraminteraksikolom.hasill1.scatterChartDataSet(hasill1.java:56)
    at com.example.diagraminteraksikolom.hasill1.onCreate(hasill1.java:38)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7896)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7885)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1353)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3530)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3699) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2267) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:230) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7873) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:526) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1034)
```

this is my second activity :

```
public class hasill1 extends AppCompatActivity  {
private static final String TAG = "hasill1";

private ScatterChart mScatter;
private String strpnmaks, strmntek, strpntek,strmnsei,strpnsei,strmntar,strpntar,strmnnull;
private Float pnmaks,mntek,pntek,mnsei,pnsei,mntar,pntar,mnnull;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hasill1);


    mScatter = findViewById(R.id.scatter);
    ScatterDataSet scatterDataSet = new ScatterDataSet(scatterChartDataSet(),"data set");
    ArrayList<IScatterDataSet> iScatterDataSets=new ArrayList<>();
    iScatterDataSets.add(scatterDataSet);

    ScatterData scatterData= new ScatterData(iScatterDataSets);
    mScatter.setData(scatterData);
    mScatter.invalidate();

}
    private ArrayList<Entry> scatterChartDataSet() {
    ArrayList<Entry> dataSet = new ArrayList<Entry>();

        Intent intent= getIntent();
        strpnmaks=intent.getStringExtra("pnmaks");
        pnmaks=Float.parseFloat(strpnmaks);


        strmntek=intent.getStringExtra("mntek");
        mntek=Float.parseFloat(strmntek);

        strpntek=intent.getStringExtra("pntek");
        pntek=Float.parseFloat(strpntek);

        strmnsei=intent.getStringExtra("mnsei");
        mnsei=Float.parseFloat(strmnsei);

        strpnsei=intent.getStringExtra("pnsei");
        pnsei=Float.parseFloat(strpnsei);

        strmntar=intent.getStringExtra("mntar");
        mntar=Float.parseFloat(strmntar);

        strpntar=intent.getStringExtra("pntar");
        pntar=Float.parseFloat(strpntar);

        strmnnull=intent.getStringExtra("mnnull");
        mnnull=Float.parseFloat(strmnnull);

        dataSet.add(new Entry(0,pnmaks));
        dataSet.add(new Entry(mntek,pntek));
        dataSet.add(new Entry(mnsei,pnsei));
        dataSet.add(new Entry(mntar,pntar));
        dataSet.add(new Entry(mnnull,0));

        return dataSet;
}
```

}

*Edited
Here is my first activity that the result I pass to the second activity

```
public class data extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button hhitung;
private EditText hkolom,bkolom,ds,dsa,fc,fy,ntulangantarik,ntulangantekan,dtulangan,Mu,Pu;
private Double beta1,Ag,epsy,As1,As2,Ast,Po,Pnmaks,cb,
        ctek,atek,zstek,zatek,fstek,fstekaks,cctek,cstek,tstek,
        pntek,vtek,wtek,xtek,mntek,asei,zssei,zasei,fssei,fsseiaks,
        ccsei,cssei,tssei,pnsei,mnsei,vsei,wsei,xsei,
        ctar,atar,zstar,zatar,fstar,fstaraks,cctar,cstar,tstar,pntar,mntar,
        vtar,wtar,xtar,anull,aminleh,amaksleh,pnull,qnull,anullsqrt,
        fsnull,mncnull,mnsnull,mnnull,mdnull,anullpakai,d,Muu,Puu,MnMaks,PnNull;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_data);




    hhitung = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hhitung);
    hkolom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.hkolom);
    bkolom= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bkolom) ;
    ds = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ds);
    dsa = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dsa);
    fc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fc);
    fy = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fy);
    ntulangantarik = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ntulangantarik);
    ntulangantekan = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ntulangantekan);
    dtulangan = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dtulangan);
    Mu = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Mu);
    Pu = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Pu);




    hhitung.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if ((hkolom.getText().length() > 0) && (bkolom.getText().length() > 0) &&
                    (ds.getText().length() > 0) && (dsa.getText().length() > 0)&&
                    (fc.getText().length() > 0) && (fy.getText().length() > 0) &&
                    (ntulangantarik.getText().length() > 0) &&(ntulangantekan.getText().length() > 0)&&
                    (dtulangan.getText().length() > 0) && (Mu.getText().length() > 0) &&
                    (Pu.getText().length() > 0)) {

                Double vhkolom = Double.parseDouble(hkolom.getText().toString());
                Double vbkolom = Double.parseDouble(bkolom.getText().toString());
                Double vds = Double.parseDouble(ds.getText().toString());
                Double vdsa = Double.parseDouble(dsa.getText().toString());
                Double vfc = Double.parseDouble(fc.getText().toString());
                Double vfy = Double.parseDouble(fy.getText().toString());
                Double vntulangantarik = Double.parseDouble(ntulangantarik.getText().toString());
                Double vntulangantekan = Double.parseDouble(ntulangantekan.getText().toString());
                Double vdtulangan = Double.parseDouble(dtulangan.getText().toString());
                Double vMu = Double.parseDouble(Mu.getText().toString());
                Double vPu = Double.parseDouble(Pu.getText().toString());

                if ((vfc < 30)) {
                    beta1 = 0.85;
                } else {
                    beta1 = 0.85 - 0.008 * (vfc - 30);
                }

                //Luas Penampang
                epsy = vfy / 200000;
                Ag = vbkolom * vhkolom;
                As1 = vntulangantarik * Math.pow(vdtulangan,2) * Math.PI /4;
                As2 = vntulangantekan * Math.pow(vdtulangan,2)* Math.PI /4;
                Ast = As1 + As2;

                //Tinjauan Beban Sentris
                Po = 0.85 * (vfc/1000) * (Ag - Ast) + Ast * (vfy/1000);
                Pnmaks = 0.8 * Po;

                //Kondisi Tekan Menentukan (tek)
                d= vhkolom-vds;
                cb = (600*d)/(600+ vfy);
                ctek = cb + 70;
                atek = beta1 * ctek;
                zstek = ((vhkolom - ctek) - vds) / ctek * 0.003;
                if ((zstek < epsy)) {
                    fstek = zstek * 200;
                } else {
                    fstek = vfy / 1000;
                }
                zatek = (ctek - vdsa) / ctek * 0.003;
                if ((zatek < epsy)) {
                    fstekaks = zatek * 200;
                } else {
                    fstekaks = vfy / 1000;
                }
                cctek = 0.85 * (vfc / 1000) * atek * vbkolom;
                cstek = As2 * fstekaks;
                tstek = As1 * fstek;
                pntek = cctek + cstek - tstek;
                vtek = cctek * (vhkolom / 2 - atek / 2);
                wtek = cstek * (vhkolom / 2 - vdsa);
                xtek = tstek * (vhkolom / 2 - vds);
                mntek = (vtek + wtek + xtek) / 1000;

                //Kondisi Seimbang (sei)
                asei = beta1 * cb;
                zssei = ((vhkolom - cb) - vds) / cb * 0.003;
                fssei = vfy/1000;
                zasei = (cb - vdsa) / cb * 0.003;
                if ((zasei < epsy)) {
                    fsseiaks = zasei * 200;
                } else {
                    fsseiaks = vfy/1000;
                }
                ccsei = 0.85 * (vfc / 1000) * asei * vbkolom;
                cssei = As2 * fsseiaks;
                tssei = As1 * fssei;
                pnsei = ccsei + cssei - tssei;
                vsei = ccsei * (vhkolom / 2 - asei / 2);
                wsei = cssei * (vhkolom / 2 - vdsa);
                xsei = tssei * (vhkolom / 2 - vds);
                mnsei = (vsei + wsei + xsei)/1000;

                //Kondisi Tarik Menentukan (tar)
                ctar = cb - 70;
                atar = beta1 * ctar;
                zstar = ((vhkolom - ctar) - vds) / ctar * 0.003;
                fstar = vfy / 1000;
                zatar = (ctar - vdsa) / ctar * 0.003;
                fstaraks = vfy / 1000;
                cctar = 0.85 * (vfc/1000) * atar * vbkolom;
                cstar = As2 * fstaraks;
                tstar = As1 * fstar;
                pntar = cctar + cstar - tstar;
                vtar = cctar * (vhkolom / 2 - atar / 2);
                wtar = cstar * (vhkolom / 2 - vdsa);
                xtar = tstar * (vhkolom / 2 - vds);
                mntar = (vtar + wtar + xtar)/1000;

                //Kondisi Beban Pn=0
                anull = ((As1 - As2) * (vfy/1000)) / 0.85 * (vfc/1000) * vbkolom;
                aminleh = (600 * beta1 * vdsa) / (600 - (vfy/1000));
                amaksleh = (600 * beta1 * vds) / (600 + (vfy/1000));
                pnull = (600 * As2 - As1 * vfy) / (1.7 * vfc * vbkolom);
                qnull = (600 * beta1 * As2 * vdsa) / (0.85 * vfc * vbkolom);
                anullsqrt = Math.sqrt(pnull * pnull + qnull) - pnull;
                if ((anull >= aminleh)) {
                    anullpakai = anull;
                } else {
                    anullpakai = anullsqrt;
                }
                fsnull = 600 * ((anullpakai - beta1 * vdsa) / anullpakai);
                mncnull = 0.85 * vfc * anullpakai * vbkolom * (d - anullpakai / 2);
                mnsnull = As2 * fsnull * (d - vdsa);
                mnnull = (mncnull + mnsnull) / 1000000;
                mdnull = 0.9 * mnnull;


                Muu=vMu;
                Puu=vPu;

                Intent intent= new Intent(data.this, hasill1.class);
                intent.putExtra("pnmaks",Pnmaks);
                intent.putExtra("pntek",pntek);
                intent.putExtra("mntek",mntek);
                intent.putExtra("pnsei",pnsei);
                intent.putExtra("mnsei",mnsei);
                intent.putExtra("pntar",pntar);
                intent.putExtra("mntar",mntar);
                intent.putExtra("mnnull",mnnull);
                intent.putExtra("Mu",Muu);
                intent.putExtra("Pu",Puu);
                intent.putExtra("PnNull",PnNull);
                intent.putExtra("MnMaks",MnMaks);

                startActivity(intent);



            } else {
                Toast.makeText(data.this, "MAAF DATA MASIH KOSONG", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);


            }
        }
    });

}
```

}

I didn't understand, I had tried researching for a solution and I'm still stuck on it.
I hope there's someone who can help me to solve it. I really appreciate it and thank you for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your logcat, I can see that you are using Float.parseFloat() to parse a null string. Can I see how your intent is being passed to this activity?

You can pass your intents from the activity you're coming from like this - Make sure to replace formerActivity with the name of the activity you're coming from:

```
Intent i = new Intent(formerActivity.this, hasill1.class);
i.putExtra("pnmaks", "50.0" (or whatever string you are passing));
i.putExtra("mntek", "60.0");
```

If you're passing a double, then you do this,

```
i.putExtra("pnmaks", 50.0);
```

and you do the same for all of the strings you want to pass into the hasill1 class. Then when you're done, you start this activity that your scatter diagram is in by passing the intent.

```
startActivity(i);
```

Then in hasill1 activity, you can get your intent data by:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String strpnmaks = intent.getStringExtra("pnmaks");
String strmntek = intent.getStringExtra("mntek");
```

To get your double value, you do this:

```
Double pnmaks = intent.getDoubleExtra("pnmaks", 0.0);
```

Before you parse your string in Float.parseFloat(), make sure that it is not empty and it is a decimal with string data type. For instance, if strpnmaks is empty - "" or a text - "boy", then it cannot be parsed as float. It has to be a number format with string type, like "30.0" to be parsed as float.

Then you can put a check to make sure your string is not null and parse it like this:

```
if (strpnmaks != null) {
   Float pnmaks = Float.parseFloat(strpnmaks);
}
```

Since you're passing a double from the first activity, I suggest getting it as a double from hasill1 activity like I put up.

Comment: I think the issue is you're passing Pnmaks and the other strings into the intent before calculating their values. Can you move the part where you're passing the data into the intent to just before the else block?

Comment: do you mean like now i post?

Comment: Does it work now? You can mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: not yet. i thought you're going to edit your comment. and i thank you cause i really appreciate it. i have stuck at this error for like a week

Comment: Are you still getting an error or a crash?

Comment: yes. i wanna ask first, the if code that you write, where should I write it at my code?

Comment: You don't need to write the if code. Since you're passing it as a double into the intent, then get it as a double. Like this: Double pnmaks = intent.getDoubleExtra("pnmaks"); Do the same for everything else, instead of getting it as a string first.

Comment: it goes error and said "error: method getDoubleExtra in class Intent cannot be applied to given types;"

Comment: Okay, get it like this. Double pnmaks = intent.getDoubleExtra("pnmaks", 0.00);

Comment: done, but on dataSet, it said "error: incompatible types: Double cannot be converted to float
            dataSet.add(new Entry(0,pnmaks));"

Comment: Then you can cast it like this. float pnmaks = (float) intent.getDoubleExtra("pnmaks", 0.00); And add it to the dataSet as dataSet.add(new Entry(0, pnmaks));